# SQL Server Cross Checking Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, validation

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 that self populates as a job in the early hours of the morning from a live database. Due to the nature of this data, it is forever changing. Occasionally due to timing, some data can be lost (often due to the fact the table takes around 30 minutes to populate and new data is incoming all the time).

Is there anyway I can write something into my SQL code that double checks there is nothing missed from the previous day? This is a live database that is populating my table.

Comment: Have you got any sample data? also, it would be nice to see the table structures.

Comment: I cant share data samples sorry but it is a very straight forward table- i just need to know the best approach to cross checking and validation

Comment: okay..but it is hard for us to help without seeing any code. Maybe you can explain how the job populates the table e.g. query structure? You could maybe include EXISTS / NOT EXISTS in your WHERE clause...